# DataGrid as custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to create my own DataGrid which can be build the same way as a normal DataGrid, but has some extra features such as filtering.

It should take types of DataGridColumns fx. DataGridTextColumn.

The reason for build my own is because its going to be used in multiple views, but with different column types with various propertys.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:MyDataGrid Grid.Row="0" GridItems="{Binding GetArtifactMdls}">
        <local:MyDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />

        </local:MyDataGrid.Columns>
    </local:MyDataGrid>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GetArtifactMdls}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

If anyone could guide me or create a quick sample it would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Try looking for CustomControl. You can derive everything from the Datagrid and your own implementations to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating a Custom Control that inherents from DataGrid and use the DataGrid template. 
Got the template from right click the DataGrid in design view and chose edit template.